# Combine keycode regex and variable array

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following code to try and only allow letters, numbers, backspace, space, dashes, slashes, and ampersands. I also want all other keys including the function keys (F1, F2, etc) to be disallowed. I feel like this code can be optimized to make it more streamlined.

This function is part of a live search feature, and I dont want the ajax request to be sent if on of the "prohibited" keys are pressed.

```
searchBox.keyup(function (e) { // DYNAMIC AUTO SEARCH FUNCTION

        var functionKey = [112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123].indexOf(e.which) > -1;

        if (!String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]\x08/) && !functionKey) {

        // code to execute if key is allowed

        }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two items I can see here which concern me. The first is that, if you have already computed the prohibetedKeyPressed, why not make the boolean check fail-fast? In other words, put the `!prohibitedKeyPressed` before the regex so that you don't have to do the regex when there's a prohibited key?

I would actually take that further, and turn your code in to guard-clauses:

```
searchBox.keyup(function (e) { // DYNAMIC AUTO SEARCH FUNCTION

        if ([112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123].indexOf(e.which) > -1) {
            return;
        }

        if (!String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]\x08/)) {
            return;
        }

        // code to execute if key is allowed

});
```

That makes the return criteria clear.

Now, the regex should probably be anchored.... but worse than that, the expression is a double-negative - *if **not** the char is **not** a letter/digit.... do something*. Now that I look more closely, it does not work at all..... it will never match anything. The `\x08` needs to be inside the character class.... hmmm... have you tested this? The search will always happen because the single key-press will never be a single-character and a backspace.... so, the ajax call will happen whenever a non function key is pressed.....

I would make the code:

```
if (String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/^[A-Za-z0-9 \x08]$/)) {
    // do something with it - call ajax
}
```

Now, having done that, why do you need the initial not-a-function-key check at all? Can't the whole thing just be a positive test?

```
searchBox.keyup(function (e) { // DYNAMIC AUTO SEARCH FUNCTION
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/^[A-Za-z0-9 \x08]$/)) {
        // do something with it - call ajax
    }
}
```